# NMHTTP component with Delphi causing error

Tags: delphi, http

After several years gap I have now started using Delphi 5 again.  My project uses the Netmaster NMHTTP component to download a file.   It used to work but now I get the following error :-

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

The request line contained invalid characters following the protocol string.

The following code executes a Get using the String urlstext.

urlstext := http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/updatesec.csv?s= ^NMX0530+^NMX570+^NMX1350' +
        '+^NMX1730+^NMX1750+^NMX1770+^NMX2350+^NMX2710+^NMX2720+^NMX2730+^NMX2750+^NMX2770+^NMX2790+' +
        '^NMX3350+^NMX3530+^NMX3570+^NMX3720+^NMX3760+^NMX3780+^NMX4530+^NMX4570+^NMX5330+^NMX5370+' +
        '^NMX5550+^NMX5750+^NMX6530+^NMX6570+^NMX7530+^NMX7570+^NMX8350+^NMX8530+^NMX8570+^NMX8630+' +
        '^NMX8670+^NMX8770+^NMX8980+^NMX9530+^NMX9570&f=snl1c1p2&e=.csv'

```
NMHTTP1Form := TNMHTTP1Form.Create(Self);

try
    NMHTTP1Form.NMHTTP1.Get(urlstext);
except
    beep;
    nmhttp1form.NMHTTP1.RequestCloseSocket;
    nmhttp1form.NMHTTP1.Cancel;
    MessageStr := Format('%8s %8s %-s',[DateToStr(Date),TimeToStr(Now),'failure in goonline.download ' + OutputFileName]);
    Form1.MessageMemo.Lines.Add(MessageStr);
    EventLog(MessageStr);
    Result := False;
end;
```

I discovered a reference through Google that this error means a wrong HTTP version is given HTTP request.   I assume this is added by the NMHTTP component (out of sight) so I am wondering how I can correct the situation.

Comment: Use a HTTP proxy (Fiddler2) to capture the HTTP request sent from Delphi, and compare it with a 'working' request

Comment: Passing "^" characters in an URL seems weird to me.  Have you tryed replacing them with `%5E`?

Comment: Even when Delphi 5 was current, it was common knowledge that the Netmasters component were buggy and inferior. They did not improve in the intervening 15 years. Use a different networking library. Consider upgrading to a Delphi version less than a decade old, too.

Comment: @mjn I have downloaded Fiddler but although it captures traffic ok it doesnt seem aware of my app when I run it.

Comment: The url string works fine if I copy it into chrome.    I am retired and so cannot justify buying into the current Delphi packs.

Comment: It also works fine in FFox with "^" but you should really consider using `%5E`.  Ref : [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: @ron did you change the NMHTTP component proxy settings so that they point to the Fiddler port?

Comment: Typo or real code `urlstext := http://...+^NMX1350'` missing starting `urlstext := 'http://....'` no `'` ?

Comment: @mjn - thanks I did not know about Fiddler, very useful.  Many years ago when I was employed I used a piece of hardware that could be inserted into a line between external ports and would display the traffic, same principal I guess.   Anyway it revealed a white space in the url string (after s=) which I did not see in the code for some strange reason and did not repeat when I entered the string on here.   I cant see a way to tick your response as an answer here.

Comment: Update:  All works well if I have Fiddler running and the NMHTTP component proxy configured for Fiddler - but if I close Fiddler and remove the proxy from the component I get  a 'missing format variable' message from Yahoo Finance.  Although the Yahoo result is probably outside this forum I wonder if anyone has an idea of why it  only works with Fiddler running.

Answer (score -1):

While not strictly a correct answer -

**Solution #1**

Please consider upgrading to latest Delphi XE6 and use latest Indy.

The problem you have is that NMHTTP (NetMasters HTTP) implements a very old version of HTTP protocol and there is no updates.

If you are still using Delphi 5, please consider using Indy for Delphi 5 instead:

http://www.indyproject.org/download/Files/Indy9.html

**Solution #2**

NetMasters sells their NM (prefix: Net Masters) components without source-code. Assuming you have the source-code, you can do a hack, such as: change the header from HTTP 1.0 to HTTP 1.1.

If you do not have the source-codes for NetMasters LLC Internet components, you are out of luck. That company is no longer in business.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It's at best a comment to the original question.